# Como percorrer uma Lista Com Map e Array List Dentro da mesma List (JAVA)SpringBoot

Tags: java, lista, for, foreach, map

[image: Hierarquia do List]

Preciso percorrer essa Lista (List)
porem nao consigo, preciso passar o valor "options",pegar o value "option_Id", e percorrer o option_value e trazer o option_value_id e Name

em resumo, é uma lista, com um Map, dentro do Map tem um ArrayList com outro ArrayList e eu preciso chegar na ultima camada para pegar esses dados e armazar em um MAP

[image: Meu Codigo]
**texto em negrito**

Answer (score 0):

Consegui Resolver, era algo absurdo de tão somples, segue abaixo a reposta em Print

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo o Codigo do Metodo complento

```
 public List<Map> ListarOptions() {
    Map configAlternativa = spiritShopRepository.getConfig(1);
    String url = url_base + "/options";
    Map header = new HashMap();
    header.put("key", util.toStr(configAlternativa.get("SECRET_KEY")));
    List listOptions = restUtil.get(url, header);//passar o Headers


    List lista = new ArrayList();
    lista.add(listOptions.get(0));
    Map option = (Map) lista.get(0);

    List<Map> mapOptions = (List<Map>) option.get("options");

    List<Map> cores = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Map> tamanhos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map map : mapOptions) {
        String nome = (String) map.get("name");
        if (nome.equals("Cor") ||
                nome.equals("COR") ||
                nome.equals("cor") ||
                nome.equals("Cores") ||
                nome.equals("CORES") ||
                nome.equals("cores")) {
            cores = (List<Map>) map.get("options_value");
        }
        if (nome.equals("Tamanho") ||
                nome.equals("TAMANHO") ||
                nome.equals("tamanho") ||
                nome.equals("Numeração") ||
                nome.equals("NUMERAÇÃO") ||
                nome.equals("numeração") ||
                nome.equals("Numeracao") ||
                nome.equals("numeracao") ||
                nome.equals("Grade") ||
                nome.equals("GRADE") ||
                nome.equals("grade") ||
                nome.equals("Grades") ||
                nome.equals("GRADES") ||
                nome.equals("grades")) {
            tamanhos = (List<Map>) map.get("options_value");
        }
        System.out.println(nome);
        System.out.println(cores);
        System.out.println(tamanhos);
    }


    System.out.println(lista);


    return listOptions;


}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.